# erro ao instalar o composer no linux

Tags: php, composer

eu alterei algumas coisas no composer-setup.php, pra tentar forca a instalacao e burla alguns ifs, mas gerou esse erro

```
The zlib extension is not loaded, this can slow down Composer a lot.
If possible, install it or recompile php with --with-zlib

The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
If you can not modify the ini file, you can also run `php -d option=value`
 to modify ini values on the fly. You can use -d multiple times.
```

o caminho do php.ini foi eu que setei na variavel, bom como o erro ja diz ta faltando o zlib que eu ja instalei mas se quiserem dar dica de como instalar e bem vindo, mas o foco e saber como eu posso dizer pro php onde o zlib esta instalado ou sei la oque devo fazer pra fazer com que ele detecte o zlib, e sobre o caminho do diretorio '/opt/..etc' queria saber como posso colocar ele no path permanentemente

Answer (score -1):

bom eu mesmo vou responder minha pergunta, todo esse erro estava acontecendo porque eu tenho o php8 instalado na minha maquina e pra instalar o composer precisa executar pelo terminal que e onde eu estava errando, no meu caso estou usando o xampp como servidor e tenha que executar o php do xampp

Tipo: se executar `php -m` no terminal

vai ser executado o php que esta instalado na minha maquina, nao o do xampp
se quiser executar o php do xampp digite
`export PATH='/opt/lampp/bin'` aqui e o caminho do seu executavel php...

depois pode da um
`php -m` e voce vai usar o php do xampp normalmente

mas lembre-se se ao fechar o terminal o caminho colocado no  PATH vai ser esquecido e voce tera que fazer novamente se quiser ficar usando o php no terminal, meu sistema e linux mint, se isso te ajudou deixe seu comentario...